# are these functors exact?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective algebraic variety over a field of characteristic zero and let $D$ be a simple normal crossing divisor on $D$. Put

$j: U \hookrightarrow X$

for the inclusion of the complement $U=X-D$ on $X$.

Are the functors $j_\ast$ and $j_!$ exact?

I think the answer is yes.

I would be very grateful if someone could provide me with a proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're asking about quasicoherent sheaves.

Since the inclusion of $U$ into $X$ is an open immersion, $j_!$ is exact.  You can find this in [Tag 03DJ](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03DJ).

Since $j$ is an affine morphism, $j_*$ is exact (EGA 2 Corollary 5.2.2).  $j$ is affine, because the affine property of morphisms is étale local on the target, and the inclusion of the complement of a principal closed subscheme (such as the locus defined by $x_1 x_2 \cdots x_r = 0$ in affine space) is affine.  See e.g., [Tag 07ZT](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07ZT)

Comment: $j_!$ does not preserve quasicoherent sheaves...

Comment: Could you explain Why not?

Comment: I should have said $\mathcal{O}$-modules.

Answer (score 1):

For a general open immersion $j: U \hookrightarrow X$, $j_!$ is exact (it is left exact and left adjoint to $j^*$), but I would guess that $j_*$ is (in general) only left exact (it is right adjoint to $j^*$).

Comment: Thanks, Timo? Is that general or you have taken into account the shape of $U$? Is the morphism $j$ affine or something that allows to conclude exactness? 

Comment: This holds for $j: U \hookrightarrow X$ an open immersion. An affine morphism is exact.

Comment: So now the question is: is $j$ affine in the situation "complement of a SNCD"?

Comment: I would guess so, since according to [Milne, Étale cohomology], Theorem VI.7.1, the complement in a projective variety of a hypersurface section is affine.

Comment: If the divisor is not ample then it is not such a hyperplane section.  For example the complement of a line on a quadric surface is a $\mathbb{P}^1$ bundle over $\mathbb{A}^1$.

Comment: Exactness is a local question.